Calculo de total general en datatable, con crosstalk y htmltools
Soy amateur de R en RStudio. Actualmente estoy intentando hacer un dashboard del lado del usuario, es decir sin posibilidad de recurrir a un servidor y/o utilizar shiny. Estoy aplicando las librerías data.table, DT, crosstalk y htmltools, entre otras. Con mucho esfuerzo, e IA mediante, logré una función que me permite crear las tablas de mi tablero. Dichas tablas tendrían un filtro general (cuya construcción no está incluida en el script que paso) y otro filtro por la variable Categoría (que está incluido en el script); ambos filtros permiten obtener subtotales y un total general en cada tabla. Actualmente son unas 16 tablas (todas tienen una data.frame en común, pero muestran selecciones de columnas diferentes). El script funciona en el calculo de subtotales y total general. El problema es que al iniciar cada una de las tablas muestra una fila de total general por cada tabla creada, es decir: 16 filas de total general... Ahora bien, al cambiar el filtro Categoria la tabla se corrige y se presenta como es de esperar. Bueno, ni con IA he logrado resolver este problema, lo que debería suceder es que cada tabla presente sólo un total general, el cual debería cambiar al variar cualquiera de los filtros.

En la imagen, además se ve las columnas del encabezado y del cuerpo de la tabla aparecen inicialmente desplazada. Aquí dejo el script de creación de las tablas y un ejemplo de su aplicación. Desde ya agradezco muchísimo a quien/es se propongan ayudarme.
´´´
CreaTabla <- function(id_FiltroCategoria, id_tabla, values_Catego, Tabla_Fuente, columnas, calculos) {
  Filtro_Categoria <- div(
    div(tags$label("Seleccionar", `for` = id_FiltroCategoria)),
    tags$select(
      id = id_FiltroCategoria,
      onchange = sprintf("table_%s.column(1).search(this.value).draw();", id_tabla),
      lapply(values_Catego, function(value) {
        if (value == "JURISDICCION") {
          tags$option(value, selected = TRUE)
        } else {
          tags$option(value)
        }
      })
    ),
    style = "margin-bottom: 8px;"
  )
  
  Tabla <- datatable(
    SharedData$new(Tabla_Fuente, ~PERIODO, group = "AnioGest"),
    rownames = FALSE,
    filter = 'none',
    class = "hover cell-border compact",
    extensions = c('Buttons', 'RowGroup'),
    options = list(
      paging = FALSE,
      dom = 'Brtip',
      buttons = c(I('colvis'), 'copy', 'excel'),
      scrollY = "250px",
      scrollX = TRUE,
      scroller = TRUE,
      autoWidth = TRUE,
      columnDefs = list(
        list(targets = 1, visible = FALSE),
        list(targets = '_all', className = 'dt-center'),
        list(targets = 0, className = 'dt-left'),
        list(targets = c(0, 2), className = 'dt-left')
      ),
      rowGroup = list(
        dataSrc = 2,
        startRender = JS(
          "function (rows, group) {",
          "let tr = document.createElement('tr');",
          "let th = document.createElement('th');",
          "th.colSpan = rows.columns().count();",
          "th.textContent = '';",
          "tr.appendChild(th);",
          "return tr;",
          "}"
        ),
        endRender = JS(
          sprintf("function (rows, group) {
            %s
            let tr = document.createElement('tr');
            let addCell = function (tr, content, colSpan = 1) {
              let th = document.createElement('th');
              th.colSpan = colSpan;
              th.textContent = content;
              th.style.textAlign = 'center';
              tr.appendChild(th);
            };
            addCell(tr, '' + group, 2);
            %s
            tr.style.textAlign = 'center';
            return tr;
          }", 
          paste0("let totalCol", 1:length(columnas), " = rows.data().pluck(", columnas, ").reduce((a, b) => parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b), 0);", collapse = "\n"),
          paste0("addCell(tr, totalCol", 1:length(columnas), ");", collapse = "\n")
          )
        )
      ),
      initComplete = JS(
        sprintf("function(settings, json) {
          var table_%s = this.api();
          
          table_%s.column(1).search('JURISDICCION').draw(); // Filtrar por defecto
          $('#%s').on('change', function() {
            var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(this).val());
            table_%s.column(1).search(val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false).draw();
          });
          
          $('body').css({'font-family': 'Calibri', 'font-size': '11px'});
          $(this.api().table().header()).css({'font-weight': 'bold','background-color': '#23448f', 'color': '#fff'});
          
          setTimeout(function() {
            let api = table_%s;
            let columns = [%s];
            function updateTotalGeneral() {
              function roundToTwo(num) {
                return +(Math.round(num + 'e+2') + 'e-2');
              }
              let totalGeneral = {};
              columns.forEach(function(i) { totalGeneral[i] = 0; });
              api.rows({ search: 'applied' }).every(function() { 
                if ($(this.node()).hasClass('dtrg-group')) return; 
                let data = this.data();
                columns.forEach(function(i) { totalGeneral[i] += parseFloat(data[i]) || 0; });
              });
              let tr = document.createElement('tr');
              let addCell = function (tr, content) {
                let th = document.createElement('th');
                th.textContent = content;
                tr.appendChild(th);
              };
              
              addCell(tr, 'Total General');
              addCell(tr, ''); 
              %s
              
              $(tr).css({ 'font-weight': 'bold', 'background-color': '#7da6bb' });
              $('table tbody').prepend(tr); // Insertar al principio del tbody
            };
            
            updateTotalGeneral();
            $('#%s').on('change', function() { updateTotalGeneral(); });
            $('#Id_Periodo').on('change', function() { updateTotalGeneral(); });
          }, 0);
        }",
        id_tabla, id_tabla, id_FiltroCategoria, id_tabla, id_tabla, paste(columnas, collapse = ", "), paste0("addCell(tr, roundToTwo(totalGeneral[", columnas, "]));", collapse = "\n"), id_FiltroCategoria)
      )
    ),
  width = '100%'
  )
  Tabla_AliIzq <- div(style = "position:absolute", Tabla) 
  list(Filtro_Categoria = Filtro_Categoria, Tabla = Tabla_AliIzq)
}

# Ejemplo: Tiempo de residencia en el barrio
TTiResi <- CreaTabla("id_FiltroCategoria2", "tabla2", values_Catego, Tab_TiResi, c(3, 4, 5, 6, 7),
                     c("rows.data().pluck(3).reduce((a, b) => parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b), 0)", # 3 totalHogares
                       "rows.data().pluck(4).reduce((a, b) => parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b), 0)", # 4 Menos de 1 año
                       "rows.data().pluck(5).reduce((a, b) => parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b), 0)", # 5 1 a 5 años
                       "rows.data().pluck(6).reduce((a, b) => parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b), 0)", # 6 6 a 10 años
                       "rows.data().pluck(7).reduce((a, b) => parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b), 0)")) # 7 Más de 10 años

# Visualización
htmltools::browsable(
  tagList(
    TTiResi$Filtro_Categoria,
    div(
      TTiResi$Tabla
      )
  )
)

´´´
